# How to add a custom shortcode below the product table on woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shortcode

**Problem:**
I need to add a shortcode `[wc_sc_available_coupons]` below the product table on the checkout page.
I added the following code in `functions.php`
The problem is the shortcode displays at the very bottom of the checkout form.
I changed the number 10 to 120 but still the same.
Would you please let me know how to add the shortcode `below the product table (=above the payment)`?


**Code I tried:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'wnd_checkout_code', 10 );

function wnd_checkout_code( ) {
  echo do_shortcode('[wc_sc_available_coupons]');
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would `woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details` hook work for you? So your code would be something like this:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details', 'wnd_checkout_code' );

function wnd_checkout_code( )
{
  echo do_shortcode('[wc_sc_available_coupons]');
}
```

If not then you could try other hooks such as `woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review` or you could try this `woocommerce_before_order_notes` as well.

This one is right before the payment:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'wnd_checkout_code' );

function wnd_checkout_code( ) 
{
  echo do_shortcode('[wc_sc_available_coupons]');
}
```

Comment: Hi Ruvee: Oh, wow, wow, you are awesome, you have all the solutions. I'd like to download your knowledge in my brain if possible hehe. I always thank you for your help, take care and thank you for editing my questions Ruvee  : )

Answer (score 1):

Use the action:

`add_action("woocommerce_after_cart_table", $action)`

OR

`add_action("woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals", $action)`

**Result**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUdtM.jpg

---

In general for WooCommerce you can find hook info here:
https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html

and for your template:
https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-cart-cart.html#source-view.159

You can see information on the actions allowed by looking at the source code in `woocommerce/templates/` and checking the `do_action()` functions.

Comment: Hi jnelson: Thank you a lot for your help and explanation, I gave it a thumbs up : )